# add link at the bottom of each image in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

How can I add links to the images in the bootstrap carousel? I don't want the links or text over the carousel. I want on the bottom of each picture. I meant after the each picture

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 style="margin-left:483px; margin-bottom:50px;"> Projects </h1>  
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/TekClasses.PNG" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/sppeder.PNG" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" style="margin-top:250px;"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="margin-top:250px;"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some simple css codes you can do. Check out this https://codepen.io/peshraw-h-ahmed/pen/JvKeME

HTML

```
<div class="w-25">
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="First slide">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h5 class="text-dark">Some example text</h5>
     </div>
   </div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="Second slide">
  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <h5 class="text-dark">Some example text</h5>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-caption{
  display:block;
  position:static;
  padding:0;
}
```